# Getting unauthorized while introspecting token with spring authorization server

Tags: spring, oauth-2.0, access-token

I want to use the client_credentials oauth2 flow, where my client sends requests through postman.

Authorization server:

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class AuthServerSecurityConfiguration {

    @Bean
    @Order(Ordered.HIGHEST_PRECEDENCE)
    public SecurityFilterChain authorizationServerSecurityFilterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        // @formatter:off
        OAuth2AuthorizationServerConfiguration.applyDefaultSecurity(http);
        http.oauth2ResourceServer(resourceServer -> resourceServer.jwt(Customizer.withDefaults()));
        // @formatter:on
        return http.build();
    }

    @Bean
    @Order(2)
    public SecurityFilterChain standardSecurityFilterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        // @formatter:off
        http
            .authorizeHttpRequests(auth -> auth
                     .requestMatchers(HttpMethod.POST, "/oauth2/introspect").hasAuthority("RESOURCE_SERVER")
                     .anyRequest().authenticated());
        // @formatter:on

        return http.build();
    }

    @Bean
    public RegisteredClientRepository registeredClientRepository() {
        // @formatter:off
        RegisteredClient registeredClient = RegisteredClient.withId(UUID.randomUUID().toString())
                .clientId("postman-client-id")
                .clientSecret("postman-client-secret")
                .clientAuthenticationMethod(ClientAuthenticationMethod.CLIENT_SECRET_POST)
                .authorizationGrantType(AuthorizationGrantType.CLIENT_CREDENTIALS)
                .scope("HELLO")
                .build();
        // @formatter:on

        return new InMemoryRegisteredClientRepository(registeredClient);
    }
    
    @Bean
    public PasswordEncoder pwdEncoder() {
        return NoOpPasswordEncoder.getInstance();
    }

    @Bean
    public AuthorizationServerSettings providerSettings() {
        return AuthorizationServerSettings.builder().issuer("http://localhost:8080").build();
    }

    @Bean
    public UserDetailsService userDetailsService() {
        // @formatter:off
        UserDetails userDetails = User.withDefaultPasswordEncoder()
                .username("resource-server-id")
                .password("resource-server-secret")
                .roles("RESOURCE_SERVER")
                .build();
        // @formatter:on

        return new InMemoryUserDetailsManager(userDetails);
    }

}
```

Resource Server:

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class ResourceServerSecurityConfiguration {
    
    @Bean
    public SecurityFilterChain filterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        return http
                   .authorizeHttpRequests(authz -> authz
                                                        .requestMatchers("/api/greet/**").hasAuthority("SCOPE_HELLO")
                                                        .anyRequest().authenticated())
                   .oauth2ResourceServer(oauth2 -> oauth2
                                                         .opaqueToken(opaqueToken -> opaqueToken
                                                                                                 .introspectionUri("http://localhost:8080/auth-server/oauth2/instrospect")
                                                                                                 .introspectionClientCredentials("resource-server-id", "resource-server-secret")))
                   .build();
    }
}
```

The resource server has the following controller:

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/api")
public class ResController {
    
    @GetMapping("/greet")
    public String greet() {
        return "Hello!";
    }
}
```

I run both apps in the same tomcat container in Eclipse and I successfully manage to get an access token. However, if with that token I try to GET the resource in the authorization server I obtain a 401.

I wanted then to instrospcet the token manually with a POST request. According to [here](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc7662#section-2) the introspection endpoint MUST be protected, thats why I have exposed a `UserDetailsService` bean indicating a Resource Server "User" with a role of `RESOURCE_SERVER` and protected the path `/oauth2/introspect` so that only that user can access that introspection endpoint via basic auth.

These are the outcomes for some requests to the introspection endpoint:

- [Using basic auth with the resource server credentials `resource-server-id` and `resource-server-secret`](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TXD7r.png)
- [Not using basic auth but specifing those credentials as `client_id` and `client_secret` as parameters in the request](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UwAzL.png)
- [Not using basic auth but specifing as as `client_id` and `client_secret` the values `postman-client-id` and `postman-client-secret`.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RBOwI.png)

Here are my questions:

1. Why does the authorization server allows the request in primis? The request does not contain basic auth headers, and the specifed parameters are related to a user that does not have the `RESOURCE_SERVER` role anyways.
2. Why do I have to specify `client_id` and `client_secret` of the postman app, instead of passing the resource server credentials as basic auth header parameters? [according to the standard](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc7662#section-2.1) I just neet to specify the `token` parameter.